# Pareto distribution and whether a chart conforms to it

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, pareto-chart

I have a figure as shown below, I want to know whether it conforms to the Pareto distribution, or not? Its a cumulative plot. 
And, I want to find out the point in x axis which marks the point for the 80-20 rule, i.e the x-axis point which bifurcates the plot into 20 percent having 80 percent of the wealth.

Also, I'm really confused by the scipy.stats Pareto function, would be great if someone can give some intuitive explanation on that, since the documentation is pretty confusing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

scipy.stats.pareto provides a random draw from the Pareto distribution.

To know if your distribution conform to Pareto distribution you should perform a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.
Draw a random sample from the Pareto distribution using `pareto.rvs(shape, size=1000)`, where `shape` is the estimated shape parameter of your Pareto distribution, and use `scipy.stats.kstest` to perform the test :

```
pareto_smp = pareto.rvs(shape, size=1000)
D, p_value = scipy.stats.kstest(pareto_smp, values)
```

Comment: How do I know "shape" value from my distribution?

Comment: You read the first paragraph of the Pareto distribution's wikipedia page : [link] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution). 
You will find out that you want shape = 1.16

Answer (score 0):

nobody can simply determine if an observation dataset follows a particular distribution. based on your situation, what you need:

fit empirical distribution using:
[statsmodels.ECDF](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution.ECDF.html)

then, compare (nonparametric) this with your data to see if the Null hypothesis can be rejected

for 20/80 rule: 
rescale your X to range [0,1] and simply pick up 0.2 on x axis

source: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.0100.pdf